# speech accent recognition data augmentation and training

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, audio-recognition, cnn

I am using a Kaggle dataset to learn more about using sound with Deep Learning.

I have extracted the mfcc features using this cool library - librosa.

However, I want to try feature extraction using CNN's and then train on LSTM. 
(Any advice here would be good, if I am on the right track)

Should I just put the raw wav file into CNN or should I do some data augmentation before that?

Link to the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/speech-accent-archive/data)